# can't change DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH inside sh script

Tags: macos, bash

I have a shell script with something like

```
#!/bin/bash
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
echo $DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

When i execute it, it shows nicely the updated 'DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH'. However, when i try to check what's in there after i run the script via

```
echo $DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

from the command line, i see no changes what so ever.

p/s/ I run OS-X 10.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `source` the script:

```
$ . ./my_script.sh
```

So that setting environment variables affects the current shell.  You are setting it in a sub-shell only.